# bootstrap-switch-button-react :How to updated onLabel and offLabel values to different language when language is changed

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I am using "bootsrap-switch-button-react" package for ON/OFF switch. When the language is changed to different language, the labels ON and OFF are not updating. But, if other link is visited and return to the same page, then the language of ON and OFF is changed.

Below is the sample code part where I am updating the language and using the switch:

declaring translation from i18n :

```
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
```

defining useState :

```
const [offlabel, setOffLabel] = useState(t("off"));
```

Here, in t("off"), off is the key which has value OFF if english is selected, and AUS when german is selected.

Triggering the language change event :

```
i18n.on('languageChanged', function(lng) {
     setOffLabel(t("off")); //sets the state of useState when language is changed. 
     console.log("language changed to : ", lng); // It works fine
}
```

In the return statement :

```
return (
     <BootstrapSwitchButton 
          onlabel="Test" //static on label
          offlabel={offLabel} // IT IS NOT UPDATING ON LANGUAGE CHANGED
          checked={...} //these properties are working fine
          .....
     />
```

Below is the whole code, (if someone is confused of above code) :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import BootstrapSwitchButton from "bootstrap-switch-button-react";
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export default function SwitchIO() {
     const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
     const [offlabel, setOffLabel] = useState(t("off"));
     i18n.on('languageChanged', function(lng) {
          setOffLabel(t("off")); //sets the state of useState when language is changed. 
          console.log("language changed to : ", lng); // It works fine
     }

     return (
          <BootstrapSwitchButton 
               onlabel="Test" //static on label
               offlabel={offLabel} // IT IS NOT UPDATING ON LANGUAGE CHANGED
               checked={...} //these properties are working fine
               .....
          />
     )
```

I hope I am clear with the problem, and any help would highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a `useState` to control the translations.

`t('key)` takes care of picking the translation automatically. Just get rid of the `useState` and simply

```js
 <BootstrapSwitchButton 
               onlabel="Test" //static on label
               offlabel={t('off')} // This will by itself take care of translation
               checked={...} //these properties are working fine
               ...../>
```

Comment: Actually, I tried that as well, and it doesnot update the language change. But ya, in both the cases, (like you suggested and like I am doing with useState), the language is changed once i visit other links and come back to this page.

Anyways, I digged through the classes used in BootstrapSwitchButton, made some changes and designed my own custom switch button. And now its working as expected.